# The media folder is not created after saving the file in the database Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-urls, django-media

I`m writing a site on Django and I faced a problem. I have a cv field in the database, in which users can store their resume, I did everything as stated in the documentation. Namely:

1. Create FileField model in ***models.py***

   ```
   class JobseekerProfileInfo(models.Model):
   jobseeker = models.OneToOneField(JobseekerRegisterInfo, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
   photo = models.ImageField(upload_to='avatars/%Y/%m/%d',
                             default='static/personal_profile/images/default_avatar.png')
   expected_job = models.CharField(max_length=400, blank=True)
   telegram = models.CharField(max_length=150, blank=True)
   linkedin = models.URLField(blank=True)
   git_hub = models.URLField(blank=True)
   cv = models.FileField(upload_to='cvs/%Y/%m/%d')
   active_search = models.BooleanField(default=True)

   def __str__(self):
       return self.expected_job
   ```

   Notice the FileField, I specified the *upload_to* argument
2. Created a MEDIA_ROOT and MEDIA_URL variables in ***settings.py***

   ```
   MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
   MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
   ```
3. Added static() to urlpatterns list in ***urls.py***

   ```
   from django.contrib import admin
   from django.urls import path, include
   from django.conf.urls.static import static
   from django.conf import settings
   import debug_toolbar

    urlpatterns = [
        path('admin/', admin.site.urls),
        path('', include('main_page.urls')),
        path('jobseeker', include('jobseeker.urls')),
        path('profile', include('personal_profile.urls')),
        path('__debug__/', include('debug_toolbar.urls')),
    ] + static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)

    urlpatterns += [
        path('captcha/', include('captcha.urls'))
    ]
   ```

But when I added file to db, media root doesn`t create
Help me please

Comment: how do you add a file to the db? you mean you created an Object in the django admin panel?

Comment: No, I don`t use admin panel at all.I  add a file in view, using ModelForms and request.FILES

Comment: Please share the part of your views.py where you deal with the form when the form is valid.